how to harvest enough penicillin in 1346?
Background
I got sent back in time to 1346, England completely naked from head to toe. I am commissioned by a powerful organization to prevent the black death that wiped out most of the population, my objective is to teach them how to make penicillin to kill off the bacteria responsible for the culling of humanity.
The powerful organization will award me an A+ grade for achieving a mortality of 40% compared to the actual death tolls. I've a few other rules like no preaching of hygiene and I can't force anyone from an affected area (e.g. by threatening them, etc.). But those rules aren't particularly important to you, my friend.
With only a couple of years left before 1351 I need to harvest enough penicillin to hit that 40% mortality rate or better. Don't worry about distribution, I have that covered. And I was reminded by an invigilator that I must best all of my other pals that are sent to the parallel universes to tackle the same problem to win a pair of ticket to witness the kt extinction first hand!
Worldbuilding Question
What method can be used using the technology available in 1346 England to harvest enough penicillin to reduce the mortality due to bubonic plague that historical happened in 1351 England to 40% or less?

@JBH --- You're presenting me with a conundrum. So! My original VTC was story based. Your edit took care of that, shifting the focus away from character choice to methods available. So, I can retract my VTC now right? In looking at the linked potential duplicate, I see that that question focuses on a specific method, whereas this one asks about methods in general. Since that question answers this question, I can now VTC again for being a duplicate, right? But wait there's more! You might (rightfully and correctly!) argue "hey, wait a minute! That question basically asks for (cont)

(cont) a reality check / feasibility thing! And also, it focuses on a specific method, whereas this one is general. Retract that VTC again!" I know that in the past I've argued that general and specific ought to be treated differently here, so I'll retract my VTC. But wait! There's even more! Going to the linked question, I see that it in and of itself is based on yet another linked question! This one! In reading through this third question, I see that (cont)

(cont) we're back to a question of the general! This would seem to be the proper query to make this here question a duplicate, so now I can VTC for a third time, only for being a duplicate this time!

@elemtilas I trust your opinion - do you believe this should be closed as a duplicate of the previous questions?

@JBH --- I appreciate your confidence! So, I was never able to retract and recast my VTCs. So, I disagree that user6760's query here is a duplicate of dsollen's query of April 2015, which is technically the closure rationale. However, dsollen's query is itself based on a slightly older question, that of EvilFonti in March 2015. I would argue that user6760's Q is close enough to EvilFonti's that it would be closed as a duplicate of that one, even if (cont)
